# How can i parse express query param to mongodb regex query?

Tags: regex, mongodb, express

I try to build a test backend with express.
And got a problem that i cannot seem to overcome.

Trying to give the query object $regex param a value from the req.query.name. But it only returns an empty array. When i console.log(laptopName) it outputs the right value that is being given as a query param.

If i just replace `$regex: laptopName` with a concrete value `$regex: 'vivobook'` i do get results.

With  `$regex: laptopName` console.log looks  like this   `{ name: { '$regex': '"vivobook"', '$options': 'i' } }`

With `$regex: 'vivobook'` console.log looks like this:  `{ name: { '$regex': 'vivobook', '$options': 'i' } }`

```
app.get("/api/v1/laptops", (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(mongo_url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
        const db = client.db("laptop_backend");
        const collection = db.collection("laptops");


        let laptopName = req.query.name;

        let query = { 
            name: {
                $regex: laptopName,
                $options: 'i'
            }
        };

        collection
            .find(query)
            .toArray()
            .then(response => res.status(200).json(response))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting laptop name directly from params such as

```
let { name } = req.query;
let query = { 
            name: {
                $regex: name,
                $options: 'i',
            }
        };
```

if you are to modify completely i suggest changing code without promise.

```
app.get("/api/v1/laptops", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongo_url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    const db = client.db('laptop_backend');
    const collection = db.collection('laptops');
    const { name } = req.query;
    const query = {
      name: {
        $regex: name,
        $options: 'i',
      },
    };
    const result = await collection.find(query);
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json({ error: true });
  }
});
```